# False IPN message "Incomplete"

Tags: paypal-ipn, status, false-positive

Application:  Adaptive Parallel Payments

Use Case Error:  When Guest user pays a list of verified and unverified users, all payments and notifications are made but an INCOMPLETE Status is reported that triggers a false:  "Your payment can't be completed.  Please return to the participating website and try again".

This is a serious bug because it tells the user to resubmit the transaction when their credit card has already been charged.

Speculation:  This error only shows up with the combination of a Guest user and verified/unverified recipients.  All other use cases work fine.  The combination of the Guest user and unverified recipients seems to be throwing the false message even though the transactions complete properly.

There is conflicting documentation about Adaptive Payments and unverified recipients.  In the case of unverified recipients, they are notified via email and required to set up and account to access their funds.  This works.  It is the Error Message that is the problem.

Any insight on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

John